# Inaccurate/incomplete search results when creating a custom search filter

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags, filtering

When I try to create a saved search filter for PowerShell, I start out with six results:

[image]

But after I add a few, now I only have two results:

[image]

Why do [powershell-v6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v6.0) or [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) not show up? Shouldn't it always show the top `n` results, sorted by the number of questions? Or is there some cutoff? It appears tags with less than 900 questions are not displayed.

Comment: It... looks like it only returns the top six results for any string and if you've already selected something from those top results, you only get five results, or four or three or two... If you haven't, you get all six.

Comment: Interesting. I assume I'm not alone in thinking this is not desirable behavior?  Also, curious why someone downvoted this... I'd love feedback if there is room for improvement on my part.

Comment: Also, confirmed your analysis. Only 6 tags can be present at all times, either in the selection box or the search results.

Comment: You can have more than six tags **if** they start with a different string... so if you start with `powers` you'll max out at six but if you switch to `powerp` you'll get six in addition to any `powers` you selected but if you then just look at `power`, both of the former two strings will be included so if you've chosen 2 `powers` and one `powerp` you'll only get three `power` results... but if you try `python` you'll get six results (plus three tags chosen) for a total of nine. I'm checking to see if this is intentional.

Comment: Thanks for checking, but as a user, even if it's intentional it's not ideal.  FWIW from my perspective.